# ceph-osd remains in "blocked" state during juju openstack-base charm bundle installation

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, ceph

I'm new to openstack and juju, trying to install it on a few test machines.

I've tried using conjure-up openstack as well as the regular juju charms bundle, unsuccessfully.

The farthest I've gotten, after figuring out all my initial maas configuration mistakes, is an almost working deployment, but with a weird error:

when ceph-osd is being deployed, it remains on the "blocked" stage with the status "No block devices detected using current configuration"

juju status:
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/24121867/

*note: IP have been redacted as xx.xx.##.## because they are public facing IP.

as you can see, the "ceph-mon" units are ready and clustered, so why isnt ceph-osd picking it up?

logs for ceph-osd:

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/24121936/

this is the last bit of info from the logs:

```
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:19:12 INFO unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log mon:45: ceph bootstrapped, rescanning disks
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:19:13 INFO unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log mon:45: Making dir /var/lib/charm/ceph-osd ceph:ceph 555
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:19:13 INFO unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log mon:45: Monitor hosts are ['xx.xx.214.103:6789', 'xx.xx.214.106:6789', 'xx.xx.214.99:6789']
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:19:15 INFO unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log mon:45: Path /dev/vdb does not exist - bailing
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:24:07 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log Hardening function 'install'
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:24:07 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log Hardening function 'config_changed'
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:24:07 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log Hardening function 'upgrade_charm'
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:24:07 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log Hardening function 'update_status'
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:24:07 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log No hardening applied to 'update_status'
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:24:07 INFO unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log Updating status.
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:29:07 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log Hardening function 'install'
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:29:07 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log Hardening function 'config_changed'
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:29:07 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log Hardening function 'upgrade_charm'
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:29:07 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log Hardening function 'update_status'
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:29:07 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log No hardening applied to 'update_status'
unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:29:07 INFO unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log Updating status.
```

Regarding the *"unit-ceph-osd-0: 00:19:15 INFO unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log mon:45: Path /dev/vdb does not exist - bailing"*

I have juju ssh into the first machine with the ceph-osd and looked for /dev/vdb and it is of course not there:

```
b3rq78:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G   18M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       220G   15G  194G   8% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
ubuntu@-b3rq78:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0 223.6G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 447.1G  0 disk
sdc      8:32   0 447.1G  0 disk
sdd      8:48   0 447.1G  0 disk
sde      8:64   0   477G  0 disk
ubuntu@-b3rq78:~$
```

I need to know how do i hone in on the problem and fix it so that ceph-osd can be deployed?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The issue for me was that the configuration file had "/dev/vdb" as the name of the drive to be used for ceph-osd

I've change the configuration using the following command from the machine running juju:

juju config ceph-osd osd-devices='/dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde'

This added my drives to the configuration file, reloaded and it worked.

*Thanks to Mr. Billy Olsen for this suggestion from the openstack bug section.*